# The minimal distance to the graph of a continuous function is attained

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b$], and let $α \in \mathbb{R}.$

Prove that there is a point on the graph of f which is closest to $(α, 0)$,
i.e. $\exists  y ∈ [a, b]$ such that the distance from $(α, 0)$ to
$(y, f(y))$ is $≤$ the distance from $(α, 0)$ to $(x, f(x))$ $\forall x ∈ [a, b]$.

---

Using the distance formula, the problem was worked down so that $$y ≤ α + \sqrt{ f(x)^2 -(f(y)^2 -(x-α)^2)}.$$

Does this prove that we have found a $y$? Is there anything else I need to prove?

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the distance is the same as to minimize the squared distance. So suggest you look at the function $h(x)=(x-\alpha)^2+(f(x)-0)^2.$ This is then a continuous function defined for $x \in [a,b]$ and an application of the extreme value theorem shows it has an absolute minimum at some $y \in [a,b].$

Comment: Could I set g(y)=(y−a)^2+(f(y)−0)^2? then g(y)≤ h(x) and then set p(x)=h(x)-g(y) which is also continuous?

Comment: @JacobRodgers I don't see any advantage in defining a separate function $g(y).$ For one thing, is this $y$ supposed to already be the $y$ giving the minimum of $h(x)$ in the above answer? [In that case the $y$ is not really a known value, so $f(y)$ has no specific meaning] All one needs is a *single* function, then use the extreme value theorem to show existence of an abaolute minimum at *some* value $y$ of the variable $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
g\left(x\right)\equiv\left(x-\alpha\right)^{2}-f^{2}\left(x\right).
$$
is continuous. Hence $g\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)$ is compact
and $\inf g\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)$ is attained on $\left[a,b\right]$.